# Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer git remotes list still contains deleted branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 and Azure DevOps; when I complete a pull request I have it set to delete the source branch. However these deleted branches still show up in Team Explorer under remotes; why is this and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `git fetch --prune` to clean up remote branches that are no longer present.

Comment: Because git is very protective with action that delete data and none is done automatically.